# Render from another controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm new to CodeIgniter (CI) and I have a very simple question. I wrote a simple CRUD controller named, say News. I'd like to render "news/index" (and possibly other methods from other controllers) on the main page of CI, that is home.php. How do I do this?

Comment: You can write common function in core controller and then extend your controller from it. `class Welcome extends MY_Controlle1{` http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: Better write common function in a your own custom library file and call wherever it required.